# Error in installing lumx angular material design framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sass, gulp, angular-material

I just tried to use the lumX as it seems promising Angular Material dev and quick development for frontend, however I am getting the below error after going through their doc spec
**https://github.com/lumapps/lumX**

```
1: Downloaded the lumx
2: Did npm install
3: Did bower install lumx
```

then on gulp build I am getting this error:

```
Error in plugin 'gulp-sass'
Message:
    core/scss/_lumx.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon
       Parent style sheet: /Applications/Angular_Projects/KM_lumX/core/scss/_lumx.scss
        on line 5 of core/scss/_lumx.scss
>> @import "bourbon";
   ^

Details:
    formatted: Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon
       Parent style sheet: /Applications/Angular_Projects/KM_lumX/core/scss/_lumx.scss
        on line 5 of core/scss/_lumx.scss
>> @import "bourbon";
   ^

    column: 1
    line: 5
    file: /Applications/Angular_Projects/KM_lumX/core/scss/_lumx.scss
    status: 1
    messageFormatted: core/scss/_lumx.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon
       Parent style sheet: /Applications/Angular_Projects/KM_lumX/core/scss/_lumx.scss
        on line 5 of core/scss/_lumx.scss
>> @import "bourbon";
   ^
```

Am I installing it in wrong way or is there any way to resolve this error, I am quite new to scss and angular, any lead will be appreciated.

Here is my folder structure :
[image]

Comment: check and copy the .bowerrc file and then do bower install lumx it will run perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue solved it by cloning the git from the repo and updating the `.bowerrc` file to include libs in current directory for bower components.

Contents of `.bowerrc` should be:

`{
    "directory": "./libs"
}`